# how to check if this string legal?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a string like this.

```
10.0.3.1, 10.0.0.0/16, 2001:db8:100:934b::3:1, 2001:db8:100:934b::/64
or
10.0.3.1, 10.0.0.0/16
or
just one ip address
```

how should i check the format ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: It does not support CIDR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following to validate IPv4 and IPv6

You can just use [inet_pton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php). returns true if the IP is valid IPv6 or IPv4

```
if(validateIP($ip))
  echo "valid ip address";
else
  echo "not valid ip address";

function validateIP($ip){
  return inet_pton($ip) !== false;
}
```

Comment: you want to check ip format is valid or invalid  right?

Comment: i need to check ip format (ipv4 & ipv6) or a range (ipv4 & ipv6). the string may like the first one.

Comment: Thanks.It seems that I can make some changes to meet my requirements.